# Refining my current code to reduce excel processing time: removing and restoring range values

Tags: excel, vba

My current code works and does the job to store the values in specific ranges as global variables and then with a button clear this data from two excel sheets and with another button restore the data that has been cleared.

The problem is that the processing time is significant as my workbook has many sheets and they are all interlinked. I wondered if anyone could think of a way to re-write the code so that it may be quicker for excel to process it?

Thanks in advance!

```
Option Explicit
Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim arr3 As Variant
Dim arr4 As Variant
Dim arr5 As Variant
Dim arr6 As Variant



Public Sub HidePD()

Dim rngData1 As Range
Dim rngData2 As Range
Dim rngData3 As Range
Dim rngData4 As Range
Dim rngData5 As Range
Dim rngData6 As Range
Dim cell As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview_Existing Portfolio EUR")

    arr1 = ""
    arr2 = ""
    arr3 = ""

    Set rngData1 = .Range("E12:I12,K12:DG12")
    Set rngData2 = .Range("E10:I10,K10:DG10")
    Set rngData3 = .Range("E16:I16,K16:DG16")

    arr1 = .Range("E12:DG12")
    arr2 = .Range("E10:DG10")
    arr3 = .Range("E16:DG16")

    rngData1.ClearContents
    rngData2.ClearContents
    rngData3.ClearContents

End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input Sheet LC")

    arr4 = ""
    arr5 = ""
    arr6 = ""

    Set rngData4 = .Range("I76:S103")
    Set rngData5 = .Range("I111:S126")
    Set rngData6 = .Range("I355:S390")

    arr4 = .Range("I76:S103")
    arr5 = .Range("I111:S126")
    arr6 = .Range("I355:S390")

    rngData4.ClearContents
    rngData5.ClearContents
    rngData6.ClearContents

End With

End Sub

Public Sub ShowPD()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview_Existing Portfolio EUR")
        .Range("E12:DG12").Value = arr1
        .Range("E10:DG10").Value = arr2
        .Range("E16:DG16").Value = arr3

End With


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input Sheet LC")
        .Range("I76:S103").Value = arr4
        .Range("I111:S126").Value = arr5
        .Range("I355:S390").Value = arr6

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If the worksheets are linked, use `application.calculation = xlcalculationmanual` before making chanhes then set it back to xlcalculationautomatic before exiting the sub.

Comment: Does your workbook also contains event macros? In that case you can also use `application.enableevents = false` at the start and set it back to `true` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

They're right (above) - There's some Application members, like **ScreenUpdating**, **EnableEvents** & **Calculation**. Using Variants the most memory, even more on 64x than 32x systems, and appears you're using 6, and they're dynamic length - which takes the most memory. If you have procedures that call other procedures, those variables will live on until it's all complete; so perhaps cleaning up the variables at the end of each sub/function.

(sorry, couldn't *Add a Comment* as I need more Reputation points! :) )

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, how do you clean up a variable? I'm hoping you can comment back on your own answer :)

Comment: When you don't need the variables anymore, you can clean up per data type, i.e. `integer = vbEmpty, Set object = Nothing, Erase array, string = vbNullString`